# How do I receive an http request with a Node.js server and then pass that request along to another server?

Tags: ajax, database, node.js

There's a lot going on here so I'll simplify this into a pseudo example. Forget about security and whatnot for a minute here. The point is to understand the functionality.

Let's say I'm running a local web server with node.js to dev a website. In the website, the user should be able to create a new account. The account information will be submitted via ajax to the node server. I then need the node server to take the incoming request and pass it along to another server that gives me access to a database. CouchDB, for example.

So here's a pseudo example of what I'd like to happen.

In the client's browser:

```
$.ajax({
  url: './database_stuff/whatever', // points to the node web server
  method: 'POST',
  data: {name: 'Billy', age: 24}
});
```

In the Node web server:

```
var http     = require('http'),
    dbServer = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/database_url';

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  /* figure out that we need to access the database then... */

  // magically pass the request on to the db server
  http.magicPassAlongMethod(req, dbServer, function (dbResponse) {

    // pass the db server's response back to the client
    dbResponse.on('data', function (chunk) {
      res.end(chunk);
    });
  })
}).listen(8888);
```

Make sense? Basically what's the best way to pass the original request along to another server and then pass the response back to the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server at `dbServer` url supports streaming you could do something like

```
var request = require('request');
req.pipe(request.post(dbServer)).pipe(res)
```

where `request` is a module, for more info look here https://github.com/mikeal/request

This is quite readable and easy to implement, if for whatever reason you cannot do this then you could take what you need from the request and manually `POST` it, then take the response and `res.send` it to the client.

Sorry if there's an error in my code, I haven't tested it but my point should be clear, if it's not then ask away.

Comment: This is a good approach. There are no special requirements on dbServer, either. This approach should work with any web server.

Comment: This almost does what I need it to. Looks like I can pipe to the dbServer just fine but I can't pipe back to the browser.

Comment: Best answer I've found out of several much higher voted questions and answers. Thanks Alberto!